# parameter url in XMLHttpRequest.open() AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i'm practicing in AJAX and i'm stuck with an html page that respondes to user's click on button, showing a specific html file;

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE hmtl>
<html>
<body>
    <button type="button" name="button1" >button1</button>
    <button type="button" name="button2" >button2</button>
    <button type="button" name="button3" >button3</button>
    <button type="button" name="button4" >button4</button>
    <hr/>
    <p id="demo">visualize document HERE!</p>
</body>

<script>

var documenti= document.getElementByTagName("button");
for(var i=0; i<documenti.length; i++) {
    documenti[i].onclick= loadDoc;
}

function loadDoc() {
    var httpreq= new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpreq.onreadystatechange= caricaDocumento;
    httpreq.open("GET", "this is the file I'm trying to visualize!" ,         true);
    httpreq.send();
}

function handleResponse(e){
    if(e.target.status==200 && e.target.readyState==XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= e.target.rensponseText;
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

if I want to use an html file which is on my pc, how can I specified it in attribute url??? If i have correctly understand, the url parameters is the url of the document that I require to server, but if this document doesn't reside on a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I want to use an html file which is on my pc, how can I specified it in attribute url???

You need a URL.

This could either be a `file:` scheme URL (which many browsers block for XMLHttpRequest for security reasons) or, if you run a webserver on the computer, an `http:` (or `https:`) URL.

The latter option is more reliable, so pick some web server software and use that.